# world files for simulating roads and tracks

Tags: simulator, gazebo

Hello I wanted to simulate a busy urban road,similar to **Darpa Urban Challenge** for an autonomous **self-driving-car**. I'm in search of simulators for that.

I've seen gazebo since its integration with ROS is easier but editing world files or indeed creating them itself is difficult. In **torcs** simulator I have seen many world files but not many sensors.  I don't want much physics in my simulation. I want a light weight simulator(for checking out path planning on an urban road) and in which creating roads are easier.

I've even searched for gazebo sdf files similar to urban city but in vain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to start by checking out [AIM - Autonomous Intersection Management](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~aim/) by the University of Texas at Austin.  It is a simple 2D simulator, but sounds like it has the features you need.

Also, you might want to search for civil engineering traffic simulators.  I'm sure there are a bunch of them.

One more option, you can use something like [MASON](http://cs.gmu.edu/~eclab/projects/mason/) a multi-agent simulation toolkit to code your own simulator with multiple intelligent agents.